# Sum up the value for each categorie

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using excel 2010 and also excel 2003. However, I am looking for a solution which works on both excel versions. I already tried `SUMIF`, however, this does not work on excel 2003. My problem is, that I want to sum up the values for each category to create a pie cart for a report.

[image]

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: SUMIF don't works on Excel 2003??? Why..it do works...it is SUMIFS that doesnt work on 2003

Comment: As Vasim says, SUMIF will work on Excel 2003 - `SUMIF(B:B,B2,A:A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On C2 enter following formula and drag down:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=B2),A:A)`

This formula is a bit heavy on resources, you might want to update the ranges to your actual data, instead of for the whole column.

See this [link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/) for explanation.

Comment: That formula won't work in Excel 2003 - SUMPRODUCT can't handle whole columns in that version, you'd need to use specific ranges, although SUMIF should be OK as per my comment above

Comment: Point taken, I put whole column range, as it is not clear how big is the OP's data range. OP should update the formula accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM((B2:B12=B2)*(A2:A12))
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to Execute, defining a narrow range instead of entire column A & B can make it less heavy on resources.

Regards,